# Typescript: type Data<T> = Result<T, DataError>

Tags: typescript

What does `<T>` generally specify in typescript?

thank you for your help.

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type Generics. T stands for Type, and is commonly used as the first type variable name when defining generics. But in reality T can be replaced with any valid name. Not only this, we are not limited to only one type variable — we can bring in any amount we wish to define.

I would recommend reading this great article which explains the same.

[https://rossbulat.medium.com/typescript-generics-explained-15c6493b510f#:~:text=This%20article%20opts%20to%20use,variable%20name%20when%20defining%20generics](https://rossbulat.medium.com/typescript-generics-explained-15c6493b510f#:%7E:text=This%20article%20opts%20to%20use,variable%20name%20when%20defining%20generics).